# Connection refused in Android client

Tags: android, sockets, client

Currently I’m working on android mobile client-server application that uses Socket to communicate with server. The application works as intended when I test it at home using my WIFI. But as soon as I started to test it in other places with active WIFI the Socket cannot establish the connection with server. I get “connection refused” exception although I have Internet permission declared in the manifest and WIFI is working. It’s strange, but whenever I test the Socket with Java client the connection is successfully established in any place with active WIFI. But when I try to do the same on Android I get “connection refused” exception.

**The error happens here:**

```
socket = new Socket(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);
```

**I have the following permission in the manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**LogCat:**

```
09-24 12:06:43.000: E/ClientSocket(21999): C: Connecting...
09-24 12:06:43.020: E/TCP(21999): C: Error
09-24 12:06:43.020: E/TCP(21999): java.net.ConnectException: /78.47.105.119:2012 - Connection refused
09-24 12:06:43.020: E/TCP(21999):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
09-24 12:06:43.020: E/TCP(21999):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
09-24 12:06:43.020: E/TCP(21999):   at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:724)
09-24 12:06:43.020: E/TCP(21999):   at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:150)
09-24 12:06:43.020: E/TCP(21999):   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:209)
09-24 12:06:43.020: E/TCP(21999):   at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:176)
```

Maybe i should set some kind of special or extra permissions declared in the manifest? Could a firewall cause this problem? Any ways to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the emulator ?
Sometimes, you need to redirect the ports
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#redirections

Try to test your code with your device (you can use it as an "emulator" with Eclipse)

Don't forget that, according to Emulator Networking IP 10.0.2.2 should be used instead of localhost/127.0.0.1 if you develop your server on local.

Comment: I'm testing it on real device.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. It showed the same LogCat. I found it was because I was using different ip addresses on the two systems. I started the server on localhost (or 127.0.0.1) and tried to connect to it using my computer's ip address on the client (192.168.1.6). It worked when I set both the ip addresses to 192.168.1.6.